# Adding a combination of leave type in the TimeOff module in the LeaveForm? Odoo13

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, developer-tools

I needed to add a feature that can combine two leave types in the TimeOff module form, and when a user submits the form the leaves gets deducted from the respective time off type. (In the form I am thinking to add a second dropdown menu where he/she can add the other time off).

I am **using Odoo13**, I am inheriting the module, but can't figure it out to add a dropdown in which the user can select multiple leaves.

**model=hr.leave, externalid = hr_holidays.hr_leave_view_form**

Work that I have done:

I have created a module which inherits the hr_holidays module in Odoo13, In the leave form i have sucessfully added the dropdown which is above but it is selecting the same time-off type which is selected above.

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<odoo>
    <!--Adding the Drop Down-->

    <record id="hr_leave_view_form_addnewleave" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">leave.addleave</field>
        <field name="model">hr.leave</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_holidays.hr_leave_view_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//div[@name='description']" position="before">
                <div class="row" name="status_id">
                    <label class="col-2 mr-0" for="holiday_status_id"/>
                    <!-- RLI FIXME: we should avoid redefining the domain in the view when there already is a domain on the model -->
                    <field name="holiday_status_id" domain="['&amp;', ('virtual_remaining_leaves', '&gt;', 0), '|', ('allocation_type', 'in', ['fixed_allocation', 'no']),'&amp;',('allocation_type', '=', 'fixed'), ('max_leaves', '>', '0')]" context="{'employee_id':employee_id, 'default_date_from':date_from}" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}" class="col-9 pl-0" nolabel="1"/>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>


</odoo>
```

In this the code with  is for the dropdown.

[The LeaveForm image with dropdowm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCe5Q.jpg)

Thanks in advance.Please look into the photo that I uploaded.

Comment: Please add code of the module you've write.

Comment: And you could shorten your view XML to show only the relevant `record`entry

Comment: I haven't written any module, just added the same field which was existing in the original form.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work that way. You need to make another field for second type and code logic how to handle information from that second field. Or actually, if you want multiple selections, you'd need many2many field.